# Swift - how to make window unactivable?

Tags: swift, swiftui, macos-catalina

I want to make application unactivable.

I mean its must be inactive and non-foreground even by click on it. Active window must be the same app as it was before click on my app.

How can I do this?

---

upd:

1. Let's imagine some window/panel. Like a Dock. Let's call it "Docky"
2. Docky is inactive, Active window is Safari:

   ```
   NSRunningApplicationSafari.isActive == true
   NSRunningApplicationDocky.isActive == false
   ```
3. I'm clicking on ANY empty point of Docky.

**Expected result:**

4. Safari is still active window. Like before click:

   ```
   NSRunningApplicationSafari.isActive == true
   NSRunningApplicationDocky.isActive == false
   ```

**Actual result:**

4. Docky is active window, Safari is inactive:

   ```
   NSRunningApplicationSafari.isActive == false
   NSRunningApplicationDocky.isActive == true
   ```

---

Another sample is Keyboard Viewer. You are clicking on the virtual keyboard, but active window is another app. Ant exactly active window getting keyPress events.

Comment: Maybe you want to explain the goal of your app in more detail as it does not seem to be clear what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: @SimonBachmann the same behaviour as have Dock. It's always inactive. It's cannot be "top most" or "active" application even if you click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually all you need is `.nonactivatingPanel` style panel. Everything else is details, like level of this window, custom views with overridden `acceptsFirstMouse:`, `needsPanelToBecomeKey`, etc. Btw, button accepts first click by default, non activating app in this case.

So your `AppDelegate`, for example, might look like the following:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var docky: NSPanel!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        // Create the window and set the content view. 
        docky = NSPanel(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 600),
            styleMask: [.nonactivatingPanel],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        docky.level = .mainMenu
        ....
        docky.orderFrontRegardless()
    }
```